# Get JavaVM and AAssetManager in native c++ Android Library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

We are using Android NDK to write a c++ library on android and the library needs use JavaVM and AAssetManager. The problem is that we find no way to access JavaVM and AAssetManager inside our library.

What I know is:

1. In native host application, we can get them from ANativeActivity
2. `AAssetManager_fromJava` if java
3. `jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)`
   It seems it can't work if the host application is also native c++

The library will be delivered to our users. It won't be elegant to force our users to set JavaVM and AAssetManager. Do you have any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover both cases in the same way ("typical" and "native" app) - the only way is next:

- Add `MyLibrary.java` to your library. That file should declare native method `MyLibrary.init(AssetManager am);`. Implementation of that method must be placed in your C++ code, where you get java reference to asset manager and then can obtain `AAssetManager *`
- Add `JNI_OnLoad()` to your library in order to obtain `JavaVM*`
- Build your library as separate `.so` to allow system to invoke your `JNI_OnLoad()`

Usage looks next:

- Client app declares custom `Application` class in its manifest
- Implementation of this custom class overrides `onAttachBaseContext()` method, which implementation invokes `System.loadLibrary("mylibrary")` and then your `MyLibrary.init(getAssets())`.